# How change root in express

Tags: javascript, html, express

I'm a web programmer rookie, and I want to do a site where when I press on a button it open me another html file, I use express, so I've tried to do something like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,  "public")));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "index.html"));
});

app.get('/chat', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "chat.html"));
});

var server = app.listen(8000, function(req, res){
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log("server in ascolto su %s%s", host, port);
});
```

but I don't know how to switch on '\chat'
and why the console.log of the listen print on my console "server in ascolto su ::8080" and doesn't print my ip?

Comment: The server is started on your localhost, or the IP is generally `127.0.0.1` Try opening `localhost:8080` or `127.0.0.1:8080` in your browser. That will open `index.html`. Similarly `localhost:8080/chat` will open `chat.html`

Comment: Are you running nodejs on a virtual machine?

Comment: @OmriLuzon no, why?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about why your IP address does not show up, but you can probably show the `index.html` and `chat.html` just by moving them to the `public` directory:

```
files/
public/
  chat.html
  index.html
  css/
    app.css
  js/
    app.js
```

You could view them by going to http://localhost:8000/index.html, or http://localhost:8000/chat.html without having to add routes for them, because ypu already told the Express server that you are serving *static* assets from the `public` directory:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,  "public")));
```

Comment: ok, I know that, but I don't know how switching the url with a button, something like: $(button).onclick(function(){ open(chat.html) });

Answer (score 0):

I resolved using:

```
window.location.replace(chat);
```

Comment: Though your way works in modern browsers, `window.location.href = "http://example.com/;` is recommended for cross-browser support.